# Return a List<class<type>> in an interface delcaration

Tags: c#, generics

I have the class:

```
public class FindResultEx<TL> where TL : TagLocation
{
}
```

And in an interface I want to declare a method:

```
List<FindResultEx<TL>> FindAllTagsEx(bool returnStories);
```

where  allows methods to be declared that return any class inherited from TagLocation. I'm sure this can be done, but I can't find how.

What's the syntax for this?

Update:

When I try to compile:

```
List<FindResultEx<TL>> FindAllTagsEx<TL>(bool returnStories) ;
```

I get:

> Error  CS0314  The type 'TL' cannot be used as type parameter 'TL' in the generic type or method 'FindResultEx'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TL' to 'WindwardArrow.net.windward.arrow.data_objects.TagLocation'.  WindwardArrow   C:\git\Jenova\autotag\WindwardArrow\net\windward\arrow\interfaces\IFramework.cs 202 Active

Comment: Maybe I dont understand the question but why havent you just made the method generic?  I.e: `List<FindResultEx<TL>> FindAllTagsEx<TL>(bool returnStories);`

Comment: @maccettura - I tried that - it gave me a syntax error. I think the "where TL : TagLocation" stops that from working.

Comment: You need to keep the `where` clause: `List<FindResultEx<TL>> FindAllTagsEx<TL>(bool returnStories) where TL: TagLocation;`

Comment: @maccettura - that was it - thank you. If you put that as an answer I'm happy to select it. (Also, I would swear I tried that but apparently I didn't.)